# Nightmare with meteor throws an exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, meteor, nightmare

I installed nightmare with 
npm install nightmare --save in my meteor project.
I then tried to run the nightmare sample code within a template helper method:

```
Template.nighmare.events({
  "click #doSomething"() {

    let Nightmare = require('nightmare');
    let nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

    nightmare
      .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
      .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
      .click('#search_button_homepage')
      .wait('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a')
      .evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a').href;
      })
      .end()
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
          });
    }
})
```

When this code is called from (I click on a button) I get the exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.electron.index.js (modules.js?hash=1ae810a…:109967)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=0969a31…:207)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=0969a31…:130)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.nightmare.lib.nightmare.js (modules.js?hash=1ae810a…:107767)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=0969a31…:207)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=0969a31…:130)
    at Object.click #doSomething (app.js:4330)
    at blaze.js?hash=813922c…:3774
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=813922c…:3743)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=813922c…:3773)
```

I have no Idea how to fix this, any tip or hint would be appreciated!

Anyone that got meteor + nightmare to work together?

If I put the same code in a test.js file and run it with node test.js in its own project works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) is supposed to run on Node, not directly in a browser.

Your code within `Template.template_name.events` executes on the Client's browser, hence your error messages.

You could probably try to achieve what you are trying to do by moving your Nightmare code into a Server-only method, and call that method in your event handler.